# Google Sheets API working for one sheet, but not another

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api

The following code works:

```
let sheet = "c750833d5021f60a1b9cc9bf0a21bb9dc74cff12"
let range = "Sheet1"
let apiKey = "6e0ece719a48d1337e69bd881b4324aa957e4407"

let url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheet}/values/${range}?key=${apiKey}`

fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => err);
```

However, with another sheet, the code does nothing when executed. What might be the problem?

Both sheets have link sharing on.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the detail information of `the code does nothing when executed`? 2. Can I ask you about the differences between the sheet that the script works and the sheet of `the code does nothing when executed`?

Comment: 1. When I execute the script with `node script.js`, nothing happens i.e. it just shows a new line in the terminal. Weird.
2. The sheet that the code works for, is a simple sheet with link sharing on. The one that it doesn't work for, has link sharing on, but it also has added people that can edit. This shouldn't change things?

Comment: As long as the person running the code has edit access to both sheets - the code should work equally for both sheets. However, I see the line `let range = "Sheet1"`.  Maybe one of the spreadsheets does not have a "Sheet1"?

Comment: @ziganotschka There is no connection between the person and the sheet i.e. the need for edit access. Both have the same settings, and one works, another doesn't. Also, the ranges are correct for the separate sheets, the `Sheet1` is just for demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand and replicate your issue, can you provide 2 sample Spreadsheets of both types that works and doesn't work? Of course, please remove your personal information.